# Jquery Fade-in with images

Tags: jquery, html, fadein

I'm creating a card game where cards should fade in, I have the following function  showCard() which accepts 2 variables, e being the span / id, and t being the name of the card, like 2c (for 2 of clubs).

I'm trying to get the cards to fade in using .delay(40).fadeIn(80) without any success. Can someone throw some pointers out there to help me out?

```
function showCard(e, t) {
    if (t == "") return;
    var n = document.getElementById(e);
    n.src = "../images/75/" + t + ".png";
    if (n.style.visibility == "visible") {
        n.className = "";
        return
    }
    n.style.visibility = "visible";
    n.className = ""
}
```

The following code is executed serverside: "actions" is simply an array of data that's caught in the jQuery listener

```
       $this->actions .= "showCard(\"split_card" . ($c + 1) . "\", '{$this->split_cards[$c]}');";
```

Comment: What is the code that you're working with? You've provided us with pure JavaScript code (but no jQuery).

Comment: Serverside : PHP, I'm using javascript client (with jQuery) clientside.

Comment: I mean, can you provide us with the code (not what languages you're using)? This doesn't show what you've attempted to do.

Comment: I don't quite understand your two `n.className = ""` why that?

Comment: Note that the delay and animation duration is in milliseconds, and anything under 100 will almost not be noticeable ?

Comment: Updated with the serverside code which sends back to the client.  I haven't been able to successfully wrap the .delay.fadeIn() function yet, really not sure where to add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `delay`. I am not sure what your exact problem is, as the code you pasted is different from what you said you did.

In any case, since you tagged `jQuery` and mentioned it, I guess you are ok using it. Then you can simply do like so:

```
function showCard(e,t){
    if (t == "") return;
    var n = $('#' + e);

    n.attr('src',t)
    .fadeIn(1000);
}
```

I have made a simple example [**here**](http://jsbin.com/usAVOge/2).

Also, obviously, make sure that your CSS is set up correctly to begin with (i.e. you can't make something *fade in* if it's already showing).

Comment: I'm getting the following error in the JS console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'fadeIn' of undefined

Comment: Do you include jQuery in your HTML file?

Comment: Yep  -actually, now I'm getting this error: Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: An invalid or illegal character was specified, such as in an XML name.

Comment: Without seeing your code it is difficult to say. Do you have a link? Can you copy it to [JSBin](http://www.jsbin.com)? As you saw, my example works without errors.

Comment: I had some css issues, mainly I didn't have the divs hidden using .hide() for this to work. Thanks for the quick responses

Comment: The `div`s don't necessarely have to be hidden using `.hide()`. A better approach would be to give them a class (e.g. `.card`?) and hide them through CSS. Obviously, there are cases in which you **need** Javascript. Glad it helped though.